# How can I prevent mutt to delete random mails?

Tags: mutt

It is a really big problem with mutt:

```
mutt                                                 1.5.24-1build1
mutt-patched                                         1.5.24-1build1
```

with following configuration for a single imap mailbox:

```
    set sort=threads
set sort_browser=date
set sort_aux=reverse-last-date-received

set editor="vim"
set edit_headers # See the headers when editing
set autoedit     # Go straight to editing; don't prompt for recipients
set forward_format="Fwd: %s"    # traditional Fwd: subject
set attribution="On %{\%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z}, %n wrote:"

set sidebar_width=30
set sidebar_visible=yes
set sidebar_delim_chars = '/'

color sidebar_new yellow default

bind index,pager \Cp sidebar-prev
bind index,pager \Cn sidebar-next
bind index,pager \Co sidebar-open
bind index l display-message
macro index b '<enter-command>toggle sidebar_visible<enter>'
macro pager b '<enter-command>toggle sidebar_visible<enter>'

set status_format=" %r %b %f %n      Del %d      Msgs %m %l %%> (%P)"
set pager_format="[%4C/%4m] (%S%Z) %%=%N $i %%> [%lL]"
set date_format="!%H:%M %a %d %b     "
set index_format="%4C %Z %[%b%d] %-15.15F %s"
set folder_format="%2C %t %8s %d %N %f"

set record="+Sent"
set copy=yes
set include=yes                         #quote msg in reply
set fast_reply=yes                      #no prompting on reply
set beep=no                             #no noise
set markers=no                          #no + on wrapped lines
set to_chars=" +TCF"                    #no L for mail_list
```

**The problem:**

I mark a single email I want to delete by `d` key, there is 55 emails in the folder. Then I open another folder `^o`, then I press `y` to approve remove of the emails and there is about 48 emails in the folder. It removes a lot of emails, I'm not sure they are random, and they are not in the same thread. It looks like if I mark 2nd email from the top of the emails list,it will remove first email and marked by `D` email too .

Any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: You fix it by reporting the bug, triaging the bug, and helping developers text the fix. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutt - your bug may already be reported. If so, subscribe to it.

Comment: I can't find any similar problems there. I thought it is something common.. As well it is very difficult reproduce to provide better description of the problem, because it removes my emails O_O I really hope that someone had similar problem would like share the solution with me.

Comment: I also asked the question at https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutt/+question/664440

Comment: Are you sure you delete mails and not converstations (ie. mail+responses to that mail)?

Comment: I'm sure, it is different mails.